# Why is it copying all the values?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Unsure why it's copying all the values and not just the values where the month isn't one.
Trying to copy just the lines where the amount of months is more than one.

And why when copying, does it miss out the first line of client Dave?

[Spreadsheet values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEJdJ.png)

```
function CopyUsersToNextMonth() {
  //define spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var month = 0;
  
  for (var counter = 3; counter <= 8; counter = counter + 1) {
    spreadsheet.setActiveRange(spreadsheet.getRange('E' + counter));
    month = spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getValue();
    Logger.log(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getValue());
    
    //if the month is not 1
    if(month != 1){
      //get range of values
      spreadsheet.getRange('B' + counter +':' + 'E' + counter).activate();
      spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('E' + counter));
      //call to second sheet
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('B'), true);
      //choose cell to paste line from
      spreadsheet.getRange('B' + counter).activate();
      
      //select the current line
      var currentRange = spreadsheet.getRange('A!B' + counter + ':E' + counter);
      
      currentRange.copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
      
    }  
    
  }
  
};
```

edit 1: added another image to show what the desired outcome is;
edit 2: added a link to the dummy

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CBLGZSzSqSHstgODKxZfI7FSq2Jtpi-1vydwFoWBYYU/edit?usp=sharing)
[Page B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXV2m.png)

Comment: There are a few improvements you should make here. You have too many API calls, there is no need for a for loop. What you want to do is get *all* the values and into a 2d array and filter them there. If yo can share a copy of your sheet, so that I can see what you have in tab `B`, and you also have a sheet where you can show what you want the outcome to look like, I'd be happy to help. Also there may not be a need for a script, depending on your desired outcome, formulas may suffice.

Comment: I will need to to this for a lot more of the database, the for loop will need a counter up to 1000, this is just so that I can get the script correct. Would this still affect the need for a 'For' loop?

Comment: Yes, the for loop shouldn't be there. With a 1000 iterations your script will become unnecessarily slow. Never read or write data cell by cell with Apps Script :)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CBLGZSzSqSHstgODKxZfI7FSq2Jtpi-1vydwFoWBYYU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```js
function CopyUsersToNextMonth() {
  //define spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetA = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("A");
  var spreadsheetB = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("B");
  for (var counter = 3; counter <= 8; counter++) {
    var month = spreadsheetA.getRange('E' + String(counter) + ":E" + String(counter)).getValue();
    
    //if the month is not 1
    Logger.log(month);
    if(Number(month) > 1){
      //get range of values
      var destinationRange = spreadsheetB.getRange('B' + counter +':' + 'E' + counter);
      Logger.log(JSON.stringify(myRange.getValues()));
      
      //call to second sheet
      
      //choose cell to paste line from
      spreadsheetB.getRange('B' + counter).activate();
      
      //select the current line
      var fromRange = spreadsheetA.getRange('A!B' + counter + ':E' + counter);
      Logger.log(JSON.stringify(currentRange.getValues()));
      fromRange.copyTo(destinationRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false); 
    }
  }
}
```

I had to separately distinguish between the ranges from the two different sheets (named A and B) because relying on active ranges and highlighting certain cells has always been tricky, at least for me, and if the user is on the sheet at the same time then it makes the task harder.

**Rendition #2:**
For really large datasets you do NOT want to loop through row by row and have so many calls to the spreadsheet, instead you want to work in batches so here is my second rendition to the problem:

```js
function CopyUsersToNextMonthBatch() {
  //define spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetA = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("A");
  var spreadsheetB = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("B");
  var dataRangeOnSpreadsheetA = spreadsheetA.getDataRange();
  //Get all data from 2nd row 2nd column to bottom row and 4 columns to the right into a 2d array
  var entireTableSpreadsheetA = spreadsheetA.getRange(2, 2, dataRangeOnSpreadsheetA.getLastRow() - 1, 4).getValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(entireTableSpreadsheetA));
  //Filter 2d array and remove all inner Arrays where (month <= 1)
  var entireTableToCopyOverToSpreadsheetB = entireTableSpreadsheetA.filter((nestedArray) => {
      var amountOfMonths = nestedArray[nestedArray.length - 1]; //Gets last element in inner array
      //Either keep the row if month > 1 OR keep the row if it is the title row
      return amountOfMonths > 1 || amountOfMonths == "Amount of months";
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(entireTableToCopyOverToSpreadsheetB));
  var dataRangeOnSpreadsheetBWhereNewTableWillBeAdded = spreadsheetB.getRange(2, 2, entireTableToCopyOverToSpreadsheetB.length, 4);
  dataRangeOnSpreadsheetBWhereNewTableWillBeAdded.setValues(entireTableToCopyOverToSpreadsheetB);
  
}
```

Not only is the solution cleaner, but the results are cleaner as well!

Comment: This is perfect! It siphones through the data nicely, my next issue (apologies) is to delete all empty rows on the sheet. so all the data is collected together. With the actual database I will have an exponentional amount of users, so cutting down on space is essential. Perhaps I could scan through sheet B and delete any row that has Cell E empty?

Comment: With THAT many data points you don't want to run a for loop like this, making constant calls. Instead gather the entire table as a nested array, and then filter out all the values that don't fit your criteria, and then take the rest and write them to the second sheet instead of using your copy method line by line

Comment: Perhaps even it would be easier to add a secondary counter, where if Number(month) is >1 then it would minus 1 from the secondaryCounter

Comment: I don't even understand what you're saying, let me take a second attempt at this in my answer

Comment: I really apologise for this being confusing, if I nail this now, then it will set me up for the future of my setup.

Comment: I feel like this is a little different and maybe you should have asked another question but here is my second rendition

Comment: Hope the variable names are not too long :)

Comment: Tested the solution and it works perfectly! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Last comment, Applied it to the real database and it's working perfectly. Once again, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for you, it's easier to read and is configurable. After all, it was written by a human, and not based on a macro :)

You need to execute `copyUsers()`. Let me know if you need this tweaked somehow, but it's doing what you had asked.

```js
function copyUsers() {
  const sheet = new Sheet('A')
  const data = sheet.getData('b2:e', ['Amount', 10]);
  sheet.pasteData('B', 2, 2, data);
}

class Sheet {
  constructor(sheetName) {
    this.ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    this.ws = sheetName ? this.ss.getSheetByName(sheetName) : this.ss.getActiveSheet();
    return this;
  }

  setWorksheet() {
    this.ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    return this;
  }

  getData(rng, filterAr) {
    const range = rng ? this.ws.getRange(rng) : this.ws.getDataRange();
    const values = range.getValues();
    const headers = values.shift();
    const idx = {};
    headers.forEach((header, i) => idx[header] = i);
    return values.filter(row => row[idx[filterAr[0]]] > filterAr[1]);
  }

  pasteData(sheetName, row, col, values) {
    this.ws = sheetName ? this.ss.getSheetByName(sheetName) : this.ss.getActiveSheet();
    const range = this.ws.getRange(row, col, values.length, values[0].length).clear();
    range.setValues(values);
  }
}
```